# AbortError: Ready check failed: Redis connection lost and command aborted. It might have been processed

Tags: node.js, redis

What does this error message means and what are the possible causes for it? I'm using node 6.10.0 and redis 2.7.1. I run Redis store in separately Docker container and the container is successfully built. After that I prime the store with access tokens that I need in my application. I do it with script and at that moment I get the error message.

Answer (score 0):

The error appears as the result of a broken connection (Your software somehow lost connection with the Redis server). 
It can be one of two scenarios (or both) - the connection has timed out or the reconnect attempts have exceeded the maximum number specified in a config.

Comment: Is there anyway to figure out? Logs anywhere? I can't figure it out.

Comment: You can check redis logs (/var/log/redis) or your app logs (I use nodejs so it's in my pm2 logs).

Comment: Thanks Avisho but I don't have any logs at /var/log/redis there :(

Comment: copy-pasted from here -> https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/issues/1292#issuecomment-355010951

Comment: @SerhatAtes, correct - it is from https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/issues/1292#issuecomment-355010951

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was a missing "bind" directive in redis config and, as a result, redis worked in "protected mode". Nodejs client didn't show the full response, so I only found the reason for the issue when connecting to redis from standard redis-cli:

> DENIED Redis is running in protected mode because protected mode is
> enabled, no bind address was specified, no authentication password is
> requested to clients. In this mode connections are only accepted from
> the loopback interface. If you want to connect from external computers
> to Redis you may adopt one of the following solutions: 1) Just disable
> protected mode sending the command 'CONFIG SET protected-mode no' from
> the loopback interface by connecting to Redis from the same host the
> server is running, however MAKE SURE Redis is not publicly accessible
> from internet if you do so. Use CONFIG REWRITE to make this change
> permanent. 2) Alternatively you can just disable the protected mode by
> editing the Redis configuration file, and setting the protected mode
> option to 'no', and then restarting the server. 3) If you started the
> server manually just for testing, restart it with the
> '--protected-mode no' option. 4) Setup a bind address or an
> authentication password. NOTE: You only need to do one of the above
> things in order for the server to start accepting connections from the
> outside.